# After 5 days the edit has not been peer reviewed

Tags: support, review-queues, tag-wiki

On September 1st edited "About" section of tag [zedgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zedgraph), however after 5 days it still shows as "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed". Is there something I can do to quicken the peer review?

Comment: It is not uncommon for tags reviews to take days.

Comment: Only users with >= 5K can approve tag wiki edits so there are way less reviewers available.

Answer (score 4):

I went over the suggested edit queue and skipped my way to your suggested wiki edit.

I was the last one to [approve](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17211625) it although it barely made it, with one reject vote.

All is good now.

*Only now I learned there should be an edit pending link on the tag wiki page. I swear I visited the wiki page to look for something like that, but I couldn't find it. It must have been the lack of coffee.*

Comment: You know, you don't have to do all that skipping. You can just go directly to the tag info/wiki page and click on the "edit pending" link. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray you can probably ... or with my lack of coffee I must have overlooked it.

Comment: I distinctly remember being able to do that before getting a diamond. It's just approving a suggested edit directly on a post. You might need 20k for it, I don't remember, but you have that. So just need more coffee.

Comment: @CodyGray It's there as long as you can vote on tag edits AFAIK